# Can we say "The student can do still better"- with the same meaning as "The student can do better ?"

Tags: phrases

A teacher remarked in progress report of a student that she "can do still better" to say that she can do better than what she did now. Is it correct?

Comment: General Reference - [still](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/still) *- happening or existing before now and continuing into the present; in spite of that*.

Comment: @FF Not in this position, where it means 'even'.

Comment: @Edwin: There are shades of emphasis, as "exaggerated" in my comment to dingo's answer. But let's face it - "even" here is effectively *better than currently, **in spite of** the fact that it is already good*.

Comment: Different part of speech: this still is an adverb-modifier.

Answer (score 2):

I've typically seen this as "can still do better (*than this* or *than that*)" or "can do better still." What I think the teacher is saying is that the student's progress so far has been good but there's still room for improvement.

Comment: It might be stylistically weak, but grammatically there would be nothing wrong with *“The student can still do still better”*. The first *still* would then convey *despite whatever obstacles the student may face or have faced*, whereas the second would convey *even better than the [implicitly, **already** good] previous performance*.

Comment: Good point. I've added an optional comparison to *"still do better"* to make the first convey the meaning of the second, which I suppose is the teacher's intent.

Comment: +1 for saying what I was also thinking. :) -- (But I don't think the dictionary excerpt you have inserted is related to the OP's issue.)

Answer (score 0):

From experience, including the word "still" in this situation indicates that the teacher sees that the student is indeed more than capable; however, lacks motivation, is uncooperative, disruptive, disinterested, etc.

Comment: I recommend that you read the _Trow_ 'Maxwell' novels. Though you probably have.